# YandexMapKit для iOS (SWIFT)

Tags: ios, swift, yandexmapkit

Не могу подключить YandexMapKit в проект. 
- подгружаю библиотеку через cocoa pods
- делаю оутлет YMKMapView в ViewController (классы карт видны, в медиа появилась куча изображений)
Однако на import YandexMapKit компилятор отвечает что такого модуля нет.
Bridging-header.h в проекте имеется.

Посмотрите, пожалуйста, проект. Я не могу найти где ошибка.
[скачать архив проекта](https://yadi.sk/d/e2cewnJn3VTPD4)

Answer (score 1):

Спустя неделю после заданного вопроса на ящик яндекса пришло письмо от YandexMapKit'а. Пишут что запустили новый MapKit, а старая версия уже не поддерживается и ее корректная работа не гарантируется. Попробовал вновь пройти все шаги по добавлению карт в проект.... О, чудо! Карты начали работать! Видимо причиной проблемы был некоторый переходной период в версиях библиотек, во время которого часть функций была неработоспособна.